# Show that for all $\delta$, we have $\|u\|^2_{\Gamma}\le c_\delta(\|u\|^2_{\omega(\delta)}+\|u\|_{\omega(\delta)}\|\nabla u\|_{\omega(\delta)})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, traces, navier-stokes

I am reading the article *On existence of weak solutions of the Navier-Stokes equations in regions with moving boundaries* from Fujita and Kato and at some point they use an argument I have some trouble to justify. Let me recall the setting.

Let $T > 0$, $\Omega(t)$ the bounded space domain occupied by the fluid at time $t \in [0,T]$ and $\Gamma(t)$ the boundary of $\Omega(t)$. As $t$ increases over $[0,T]$ it generates a $(t, x)$-domain $\hat \Omega$ and $(t, x)$-hypersuface $\hat \Gamma$ defined by
\begin{align}
\hat \Omega = \bigcup_{t \in [0,T]} \{t\} \times \Omega(t),\\
\hat \Gamma = \bigcup_{t \in [0,T]} \{t\} \times \Gamma(t).
\end{align}
We can introduce the auxiliary bounded domain $B$ such that $\Omega(t) \subset B$ for all $t$ and we set $\hat B = B \times [0,T]$. For $\delta > 0$, we denote $\omega_{i}(t, \delta)$ and $\omega_{e}(t, \delta)$ the interior and exterior boundary strip of $\Omega(t)$ with width $\delta$ respectively, i.e.
\begin{align}
\omega_{i}(t, \delta) &= \{x~|~ x \in \Omega(t), ~\text{dist}(x, \Gamma(t)) < \delta \},\\
\omega_{e}(t, \delta) &= \{x~|~ x \in \Omega(t)^c, ~\text{dist}(x, \Gamma(t)) < \delta \}.
\end{align}
Moreover, we define
\begin{align}
\hat \omega_{i}(\delta) &= \{(t, x)~|~ t \in [0,T], ~x \in \omega_{i}(t, \delta) \},\\
\hat \omega_{e}(\delta) &= \{(t, x)~|~ t \in [0,T], ~x \in \omega_{e}(t, \delta) \}.
\end{align}
Finally, we have
$$\hat D_0(\hat B) = \{\varphi \in C^\infty(\hat B)~|~\text{supp } \varphi \subset \hat B, ~\nabla \cdot \varphi = 0\},$$
and we denote by $\hat H_0^1(\hat B)$ the completion of this space under the norm
$$\|u\|^2 = \iint_{\hat B} |\nabla u|^2dxdt.$$
Now the authors states that following result:
[image]

where $\hat \gamma$ is the trace operator. I really have no idea what they mean by "standard calcultation", they do not give any reference nor hint to do this calcultation.. Does one of you have an idea where I could find a way to show this ?